# Give Function Unique Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wanting to bind a DIV.ID to a click event.  I need to make each click event unique due to some project specs, but I just need to be able to add `this.id` to this code.   I have tried several ways, but I will post this code raw:

```
$('#add_('this.id')').click(function() {
    alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

Thanks,
Brandon

Comment: First of all I think you made a "big" mistake. In my eyes you have to write: $("#add_('"+this.id+"')").click(function() { because this.id is a variable.

Comment: you probably don't need to make each click event unique. You can determine the element that triggered the event from the event handler.

Comment: Each click is already unique and can be identified by it's id as zzzzBov stated above. Just use $(this).id within the clicks call back to find out which element you have clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#add_' + this.id).click(function() {
    alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('#add_(' + this.id + ')').click(function() {    
    alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

It's also worth noting that brackets `(` and `)` are not technically allowed in an elements' `Id` attribute, although they may work thanks to tolerant browsers.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively:

```
//for all elements which id starts with "add_"

$('[id^="add_"]').click(function() {

   alert(this.id);

   if (this.id == 'add_something') {
     //do something
   }

});
```